# Docker project structure with git submodules

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

When I see git projects which use Docker, then docker is just added to the git project which contains the source code **one** application.
But what if I want to use docker-compose to orchestrate multiple of my git-projects, because they work together (backend, frontend, ...)?

For now, I use the source code from two other git projects and some more self-created Dockerfiles - so my compose-file now has 7 services (also some public ones from docker hub).
I also need to create slightly different .yml files for different use cases (just with different environment variables). 
Is there any best practise how to structure such a project?

My project looks like this:

```
my-project/
|__ env/
|   |__ service-1/
|   |   |__ default.env
|   |   |__ usecase-1.env
|   |__ service-2/
|       |__ default.env
|       |__ usecase-1.env
|__ override/
|   |__ usecase-1.yml
|__ src/
|   |__ service-1/
|   |   |__ service-1/ (git submodule)
|   |   |__ Dockerfile
|   |__ service-2/
|       |__ Dockerfile
|__docker-compose.yml # default .yml, containing service-1 and service-2
```

So if there is a new use case, I create a new `usecase-2.yml` inside override/ and also some new `usecase-2.env` files inside my env/ folder.

For myself it's logical but I wonder what is best practise - becasue I don't find any similar project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use **[git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, then you need to group by service, not by `env` and `src`:

```
my-project/
|__ service-1/
|   |__ env/
|   |__ src/
|   |__ Dockerfile
|__ override/
|   |__ usecase-1.yml
|__ service-2/
|   |__ env/
|   |__ src/
|   |__ Dockerfile
|__docker-compose.yml # default .yml, containing service-1 and service-2
```

That way, `service-1` and `service-2` can be git repos of their own that you can add as submodules in the main parent repo '`my-project`'.